# split data frame keep at least one factor in both subsets

Tags: r, dataframe, split, factors

I have a data frame of 200k rows, 10 columns. ( only include 3 here for ease of reading)

```
df=data.frame(A=rep(letters[1:20],10000),B=rep(letters[2:21],10000),C=rep(letters[3:22],10000))
```

I am trying to split the data into two subsets - training and testing.

```
s=sample(dim(df[1],.6*dim(df)[1])
training=df[s,]
testing=df[-s,]
```

Is there a way to take a sample from df such that there is at least one factor in each of the resulting subsets? That is, from column A-J, I want at least one instance of each of the factors in both the training and testing sets.

I tried [Random subset containing at least one instance of each factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516637/random-subset-containing-at-least-one-instance-of-each-factor) but cannot apply it to multiple columns, as opposed to the single on used in the example.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353057/sampling-a-specific-age-distribution-from-a-dataset

Comment: @Dave2e that example holds for a single variable, not for the 10 I am interested in splitting

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to do stratified sampling. There are a few options to do so in R, e.g. `strata` in the `sampling` package. Check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479512/stratified-random-sampling-from-data-frame-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

```
s=createDataPartition(paste(df$A, df$B,df$C),p=.6,list=FALSE)
training=df[s,]
testing=df[-s,]
```

worked